# how to create private key + CSR signed by a custom CA

Tags: ssl

I am trying to generate a private key + certificate ... certificate need to be signed by CA.

I generate a CA with openssl,

key:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -passout pass:xxxx -out ca.pass.key 4096
openssl rsa -passin pass:xxxx -in ca.pass.key -out ca.key
```

cert:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -key ca.key -out ca.pem
```

Now generate client key + cert with keytool ...

```
keytool -genkey -alias clientkey -keystore clientkeystore.p12 -keyalg RSA -storetype PKCS12 -validity 3650
```

Is possible to add sign with CA with Keytool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After generating the key:

1. Use `keytool -certreq` to generate a file containing the CSR.
2. Use `openssl x509 -signkey` to sign the CSR and generate an X.509 certificate.
3. Use `keytool -importcert` to import the signed X.509 certificate; it will be automatically associated with the internally generated private key.

You might want to try tools such as [Portecle](http://portecle.sourceforge.net/) or [Keystore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/) for Java keystore management.

See other examples:

- https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-java.htm
- https://knowledge.digicert.com/generalinformation/INFO227.html
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/HW94A/com.ibm.acc.8731.doc/creating_a_java_keystore_mobile_interface.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/ggezu/index.html
- https://www.entrustdatacard.com/knowledgebase/how-do-i-generate-a-2048-bit-csr-using-java-keytool

Comment: you are the man ... works perfectly 

I just signed with 
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in ${CLIENT_ID}.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca.key -set_serial ${CLIENT_SERIAL} -out ${CLIENT_ID}.pem